# Koshering canning jars

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

If someone cans using Ball brand glass canning jars (and new lids are used every time, so nothing to worry about with those), In the normal canning process, the jars are boiled to sterilize them prior to the addition of food.  Is this sufficient to kasher the jars so that we do not have to worry if the jar previously contained dairy or meat?

Whatever one puts in the jars is effectively cooked in the jars as one has to bring it to a high heat for a sustained period of time.

Comment: Ashkenazim do not routinely kasher from milk to meat or vice versa.

Comment: I know you cannot kosher between meat and milk; so if these jars are only in use for a similar item then boiling, and reusing is sufficient but if it is meat, and next year, dairy, no? Does this include spice jars; fully glass and cork that are only in use for the same spice - after initial boiling?

Comment: Is there something special abou this brand of canning jar that make sit differnt than any standard glass jar, like an applesauce jar? (That's what I use.)

Comment: @YehudaW curtain Ashkenazi Hasidim do